# Complex Variable Names In Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I am storing coordinate data in a database for a simple board game app and I'm attempting to simplify the template by doing fewer loops in it.

My template is something similar to this currently

```
{% for y in yrange %}
    <tr>
       {%for x in xrange %}
           <td class='mapTile _{{x}}-{{y}}' data-y='{{y}}' data-x='{{x}}'>
           </td>
       {%endfor%}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And assuming im passing a dict called `itemLocations` that contains an X and Y coordinate in the key like `{'1-1':'Data About Item'}`. I'd like to be able to do lookups directly from that dict inside of the `<td>` but I cant figure out if thats possible. Something along the lines of:

```
{% for y in yrange %}
    <tr>
       {%for x in xrange %}
           <td class='mapTile _{{x}}-{{y}}' data-y='{{y}}' data-x='{{x}}'>
               {% if x + '-' + y in itemLocations.keys %}
                   #Render Item Data In This Space#
               {% endif %}
           </td>
       {%endfor%}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Sorry if that question meanders, id be glad to provide any further info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you find yourself thinking "I need to do [this complex thing] in a template", your first answer should be to write a custom tag or filter. In this case, you probably want an inclusion tag - that is, move the `if` block with the #Render Item Data In This Space#" markup into its own separate template fragment file, and write a tag along these lines:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('_render_item_location.html')
def render_item_location(locations, x, y):
    key = "%s-%s" % (x, y)
    if key in locations:
        context = {'location': location[key]}
    else:
        context = {}
    return context
```

Now your template fragment can just do `{% if location %}whatever{% endif %}`, and your original template has `{% render_item_location itemLocations x y %}`.

Note I've made a tweak to your code - with a dictionary, `x in my_dict` searches the keys anyway, so no need to explicitly call `keys()`.

Comment: Thanks, I've been reluctant in the past to get into custom tags but this was the perfect situation to try them out!